# InnoDB Buffer pool not showing as much I configured in MariaDB 10.5

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mariadb-10.5

I'm using MariaDB 10.5 on Centos7 with 4G RAM and 2 CPU.

Here's my.cnf configuration

```
[mysqld]
log-error=/var/lib/mysql/mysql-3.kannel.com.err
max_allowed_packet=1G

event_scheduler = ON
innodb_file_per_table=ON
#innodb_file_format=Barracuda
innodb_buffer_pool_size=3G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=6
innodb_log_file_size=1G
innodb_log_files_in_group=1
innodb_log_buffer_size=32M
innodb_log_write_ahead_size=32M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
innodb_read_io_threads=32
innodb_write_io_threads=128
innodb_io_capacity=10000
innodb_thread_concurrency=6
innodb_flush_method=o_direct


join_buffer_size=128M
sort_buffer_size=20M
read_rnd_buffer_size=128M
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
open_files_limit=10000
default-storage-engine=InnoDB
max_connections = 500

# CACHES AND LIMITS #
tmp-table-size                 = 20M
max-heap-table-size            = 32M
query-cache-type               = 1
thread-cache-size              = 50M
table-definition-cache        = 128M
table-open-cache               = 128M
query_cache_size = 50M
query_cache_limit=128M
```

But when I see InnoDB engine status using `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G;` it gives me below information where `Buffer pool size   193296` but `Total large memory allocated 3288334336`

```
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total large memory allocated 3288334336
Dictionary memory allocated 19166328
Buffer pool size   193296
Free buffers       179141
Database pages     49186
Old database pages 18176
```

So if `Buffer pool size   193296`, where rest of the memory is being allocated?

Thanks!

Comment: note innodb_buffer_pool_instances is deprecated. Are you really expecting 50M threads? query_cache should be disabled, its horrible on MySQL/MariaDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unsafe to raise values arbitrarily.  It often leads to swapping, which makes performance *worse*.

```
max_allowed_packet=1G  -- dangerously high; wastes RAM; set to 1% of RAM
innodb_buffer_pool_size=3G   --Since you have only 4GB, lower to 2G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=6  -- only 1 per GB, so: 2
innodb_log_files_in_group=1   -- Use the standard of 2
innodb_log_write_ahead_size=32M  -- waste of RAM; leave at default (8K)
innodb_write_io_threads=128  -- too high
innodb_io_capacity=10000   -- do you have a super-duper SSD?  Else too high
join_buffer_size=128M    -- lower to 1% of RAM
read_rnd_buffer_size=128M  -- lower to 1% of RAM
max_connections = 500    -- the default will save RAM
```

As for "Buffer pool size   193296" -- That is pages.  Multiply by 16K to get about 3G.  So it is not "small".

Comment: Thanks for valuable suggestion and sharing your experience with us. Please help me to understand why Buffer Pool Size is in few KBs despite I'm allocating 3G to InnoDB buffer pool.

Comment: I just came to know, as default page key block size is 16K in InnoDB, if we multiply the number with 16 it's almost same to 3G. So it's showing number of buffer pages not size. Please correct  me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @RajeshRanjan - Ah, yes.  I forgot to point that out.  I was side-tracked into pointing out that 3GB in a 4GB of RAM is dangerously high, which can lead to slow swapping.

Comment: Thanks @Rick James for you valuable time.

Comment: What checkpoint pct you suggest for write intensive database?

Comment: @RajeshRanjan - _Usually_ I can find a way to avoid "write intensive".  What type of app is yours?  Lots of one-row inserts by lots of users?  Bulk loading of gigabytes of data?  What?

Comment: We message processing app, which makes 1 insert and 3 updates. 1 insert for message initiated 3 updates for status of the message like initiated ,sending delivered. We get thousands of transaction/seconds but not able to process those transaction on time so we are facing large queue in RabbitMQ and latency. We also have read request but 1-2% in compare of writes.

Comment: @RajeshRanjan - Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, a sample `INSERT` and samples of the 3 `UPDATEs`.  There may be things we can do to improve the indexing or something else.  Also, do you ever delete the items?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110899/discussion-between-rajesh-ranjan-and-rick-james).